# Send generated image to browser using Play framework

Tags: java, image-processing, playframework

I'm trying to output a generated image using Play. I'm not sure if my issue is Play-specific or not.  I'm trying to do the same thing this PHP code does:

```
header("Content-type: Image/png");
$map = imagecreatefrompng("$_SESSION[ROOT]/it/cabling/maps/${building}_$floor.png");
... // add annotations
imagepng($map);
```

It looks like I need to use `renderBinary`, but I'm not sure how to get from a `BufferedImage` to the `InputStream` that `renderBinary` wants as its argument.

`Application.map` action:

```
public static void map(String building_code, String ts_code) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("public/images/maps/" + building_code + "_" + ts_code.charAt(0)));
    ... // Overlay some additional information on the image
    // do some sort of conversion
    renderBinary(inputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an example in the source code for `Images.Captcha` which led to this solution:

```
public static void map(String building_code, String ts_code) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("public/images/maps/" + building_code + "_" + ts_code.charAt(0) + ".png"));
    ... // add annotations
    ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(image);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    Response.current().contentType = "image/png";

    renderBinary(bais);
}
```

which is referenced using `<img id="map" src="@{Application.map(ts.building.code, ts.code)}" width="100%">` in the view template.

For some reason it works even without specifying the content type but I'm not sure how.  The code in `Images.Captcha` had it so I kept it, at least until I find out why it works without it.

Comment: Why do you create the ImageInputStream is, it's not used later on?

Comment: @AlexanderKjäll another artifact carried over from the method I copied--I wasn't sure what it did so I just left it, assuming the framework authors had a reason for it. You could certainly try removing it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of renderBinary methods, one of which simply takes a File as a parameter.
See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/mvc/Controller.html#renderBinary(java.io.File)

So, your code needs to be as simple as

```
public static void map(String building_code, String ts_code) throws IOException {
    renderBinary(new File("public/images/maps/" + building_code + "_" + ts_code.charAt(0)));
}
```

Comment: I should've made it clearer in my question, but I'm not just displaying the image as is.  I'm loading a base image which I'm going to overlay some information on and then I need to render the result.

Comment: Ah, in which case, the solution by @bemace should offer you the answer.