# Returning image from remote server play framework java

Tags: java, playframework, response, mime-types

I tried to return the image as shown below:

return ok(new File("http://example.com/dpa/client_name/images/client_log.jpg"));

but the method in the controller couldn't fetch the image from the remote server and threw a image not found exception.

How do I retrieve an image from the remote server and return as a response using java play framework?

Comment: Why would you not directly redirect the browser to the image on the remote server?

Comment: I have to return the image to a client request in his website's iframe.

Comment: as per Benchik's answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20838010/2129212
He is reading the file from the local public folder. I want to read it from the web(remote path) and then return it from the function fetching it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use [WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS)

```
package controllers;

import play.libs.ws.WSClient;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import javax.inject.Inject;


public class HomeController extends Controller {

    @Inject WSClient ws;

    public CompletionStage<Result> index() {
        return ws
          .url("http://www.maine-coon-cat-nation.com/image-files/orange-maine-coon-cat.jpg")
          .get()
          .thenApply(file -> ok(file.getBodyAsStream()).as("image/jpeg"));
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a million for your answer. How do I use CompletionStage<Result> further? I want to send data to the intended user through JSON.

Comment: `public CompletionStage<Result> index()` is the "ouput point", you need to "bind" it to the url in the `conf\routes` file, like `GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index`. 

You can read how to serve JSON responses in the documentation "https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJsonActions#serving-a-json-response"

I am not sure that send image through JSON is a good idea, you will need to code it's somehow, like base64 or so